# How can I get shaded, labelled regions on Desktop in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp

I've seen these shaded, labelled regions on people's XP Desktops, used to group icons - in cases where the background is otherwise just a plain colour.  How can I get these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using [Fences from Stardock](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/)

From the site:

> Fences is a one-of-a-kind program,
>   allowing you to draw labeled shaded
>   areas on your desktop, which become
>   movable & resizable containers for
>   your desktop icons. These groups can
>   help bring organization and
>   consistency to your computer's
>   desktop, solving the "constant mess"
>   problem that has plagued the desktop
>   since its inception.
>
> Fences also helps you finally
>   appreciate the wallpaper you have
>   hiding behind all that clutter. In
>   addition to its organizing features,
>   Fences offers a patent-pending
>   quick-hide feature. Double click your
>   desktop, and all your icons will fade
>   out. Double click again, and they'll
>   return.

This image is for Vista, but it works on XP as well.

[image]

Comment: Cool upvoted definitely have to check this out. Better then my 'custom wallpaper' lol